# ScrollView UI Issue in ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, scrollview

I am new to `ios 7`. I have to create an `iPhone` App which supports `ios` version `6.0`.I created an `Empty Application` and I am using `StoryBoard` for designing `UI's`.

[image]

This is the screen that is generated in `ios 6.1.3`.  On landscape mode the design is :

[image]

I am unable to see the field Firstname and its `textfield`.I haven't used AutoLayout.Here is the design View in xib.

[image]

It should support both the landscape and portrait orientations.How Can I do that?

In ios 7, the same UI in simulator is :

[image]

Please help me to solve this UI Issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uncheck the `Adjust ScrollView Insets`, like this to solve that issue of not showing firstname textfield.

[image]

and your other problem will be solved by using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set every view controller to edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone for iOS7 version. If you set this the component alignment will be proper as per iOS6 version.

Hope this may be helpful